# django i18n : gettext didn't translate one line

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

UPDATE:

I solve it by use `&#37;` to replace `%`

```
<h3>{% trans "Is it 100&#37; free?" %}</h3>
```

Do anyone have better solution ??

Original question:

I use gettext to translate to chinese,But this line didn't not translate .
still output  `Is it 100% free?`
Please someone guide me  Thank you.

template :

```
<h3>{% trans "Is it 100% free?" %}</h3>
```

django.po

```
#: templates/help.html:5
#, python-format
msgid "Is it 100%% free?"
msgstr "完全免費嗎？"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is still an open issue, but you can solve it like

```
{% blocktrans with PERCENT_SIGN = u'%'  %}
      Is it 100{{PERCENT_SIGN}} free?
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Or try this way  ( bug seems to be fixed)

```
msgstr "完全免%% 費嗎？"
```

You place %% to where it belongs, i dont know chinese.

One of them (or both of them) should work

Comment: met a mistake ````Unknown argument for u'blocktrans' tag: u'PERCENT_SIGN'.```` still research.antway,thank you very much.

Comment: @user2492364 sorry i forgot "with", updated the answer. Try this one

Answer (score -1):

I like google translate. only add script in HEAD 
https://cloud.google.com/translate/?gclid=CKy-tanppsICFYTacgod5J8AYA